# How to handle "Passthrough loop detected" requests in mockttp

Tags: node.js, mockttp

I have set up mockttp to intercept HTTPS requests and do some logging, with a rule like this:

```
import * as mockttp from 'mockttp'

const https = await mockttp.generateCACertificate()
const caFingerprint = mockttp.generateSPKIFingerprint(https.cert)
const server = mockttp.getLocal({ https })

await server.forAnyRequest().matching(request => doesMatchCriteria(request)).thenPassThrough({
    beforeRequest: request => doSomethingWithRequest(request),
    beforeResponse: response => doSomethingWithResponse(response)
})
```

This is all working as expected to point my browser at this proxy server with the trusted `caFingerprint` value. Requests are getting passed through and `beforeRequest` and `beforeResponse` are getting called.

I would also like to be able to make HTTP requests to the proxy server itself while it is running to dynamically configure the behavior of the logging, but I am struggling to define a rule to catch all such requests.

I have tried defining individual rules like this:

```
await server.forGet(`/some/path`).forPort(server.port).always().thenCallback(callbackFn)
```

With this rule, any `GET` request to `/some/path` on the port mockttp is running on does get handled by this. But I would like to be able to capture all requests, not just particular paths.

I could do something like this:

```
await server.forAnyRequest().forPort(server.port).always().thenCallback(callback)
```

But this rule would handle all requests on the same port, even if they were intended for a different server. For example, if it is port 8000, then requests to example.com:8000 would also be handled by this, even though I only want to handle requests to the proxy server itself.

I have noticed when the server is running on port 8000, and I make a request to e.g. localhost:8000/some/path/not/defined/by/a/rule, I get this error:

> Failed to handle request: Passthrough loop detected. This probably means you're sending a request directly to a passthrough endpoint, which is forwarding it to the target URL, which is a passthrough endpoint, which is forwarding it to the target URL, which is a passthrough endpoint...

I'd love to define a rule that would handle all requests where a passthrough loop is detected so I can handle all requests made to e.g. localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000 or my-mockttp-proxy-server:8000. Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, I'm considering starting a separate http server on a different port to handle these additional endpoints. Would that be a better solution?